# Analyzing the Resource Monitor: Network Activity

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, svchost, resource-monitor

I am starting to look at my network activity to determine if there's anything on my system communicating with the outside world that shouldn't.  How do I determine what is valid and needed?

For example, I had no network activity for a minute, but I still had the following communicating at over 1 KB/sec:
svchost.exe (LocalService and NoImpersonation), Address: 239.x.x.x

Others I know are needed, with my router IP.

**Edit:**
For the example I gave, the destination is 239.255.255.250:1900
Location http:// 192.168.1.2 :2869/upnphost/udhisapi.dll?content=uuid:090dfd23-5421-4924-97ab-8968907a1da0
I'm guessing it's Windows Media Player based on what I've seen, though I never ran the 'startup'/installation for it, so it shouldn't have permission to spread information (unless Windows OS license agreement is somehow tied to that).

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to find out who it is talking to.  Goto a whois IP lookup site such as [Whois Lookup](http://www.whatismyip.com/ip-tools/ip-whois-lookup/) and enter the 239.x.x.x address,  you should then have an idea who the service is communicating to.

Comment: That didn't really help because 239.255.255.250 is a multicast address.  Is there a way to see what addresses the multicast is directed at?  or if svchost.exe is supposed to multicast?

Comment: Do you have Windows Live Messenger installed?  I found some old pages that refer to Messenger Traffic to the IP and Port you reference, but they are XP Specific. http://www.windowsnetworking.com/kbase/WindowsTips/WindowsXP/RegistryTips/Network/DisableWindowsMessengerbroadcastsonUDPport1900.html